# AJAX crashes browser (200MB response)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an API that returns a list of objects of my entire database with join. (Yes, everything is needed, it is a cool report :))

When I did not have 1 of the tables, the data was 150MB, and everything was OK.
I now have a problem, that I added a big table, (50MB), and it crashes the browser.

Is there a way to get a 200MB response without crashing the browser?

Comment: send it via parts?

Comment: `Yes, everything is needed, it is a cool report`. If that's your attitude towards it, then no, there's no way to do it. Work harder to find efficiencies, they exist.

Comment: From a pure usability perspective displaying 200MB worth of data without some sort of paging in place is horrible. I would recommend pulling a subset and step through it as they need it. All of that data will need to be parsed then stored in RAM taking up even more than 200MB of RAM so no you cannot stop it from crashing.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should cut something. But make it via pages.

Comment: Don't use Ajax and do direct request to server, output via server language (e.g. PHP). Outputting 200MB via JS WILL kill your browser.

Comment: What happens when you add yet another table in the future? Sending everything down the line at once just isn't scale-able.

Comment: There's something wrong with your architecture... heavy data shouldn't be handled client-side.

Comment: FYI, I've got a **large** (haha) JS application that I have developed and am getting to the point now where I am sending **2.5MB** at the same time and have seriously started to think about re-architecting it. If the only way your app will work is if you have all 200MB of data in scope at the same time, then you've built it wrong.

Comment: This is a back office application, about a specific report. Loads once per session, and has so many graphs, tables, data analysis, that I cannot chunk the data

Comment: Then split up the application. You've built it wrong. Start separating your code into sub-applications that run in separate windows to fix it. Nobody on this forum or any other is going to be able to give you an answer on how to load 200MB of data into a browser's memory for a single page application and have it not crash the browser, let alone run anywhere near efficiently. There's a reason you won't find a good answer - none exists.

Comment: pretty cool application: main UX issue will be `Who is pressed F5?` It's loading again :'(

Comment: You can start making an only ajax call for each component and building a pager for the tables. And obviously DONT bring all the data from the server and process it in the client. I guess the most heavy part comes from the data for your datatables

Comment: It's frustrating that everyone assumes web browsers are still trapped in 1995.  You know, we have full blown applications built client-side now.  It's perfectly reasonable to assume that someone has a use case where they actually need that data.  It's also frustrating that some of you think that a 200MB HTML page would be any better.  Please, open your minds a bit to the idea that this is possible, and will become more commonplace in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Assuming that you do need all this data in the browser, and that you're willing to accept the performance implications of working with a large data set...*

The problem here likely isn't in the raw size of the data itself, but the format you have it in.

If you dump 200MB into JSON and expect your browser to parse that and create a single object in memory with all that data, you're going to have a bad time.  Same is true with XML.  Additionally, I suspect that with a 200MB download, you want to show some progress to the user as you load the data... maybe even show some of that data as it's loaded.  The solution to all of this is to chunk your data.  I'm guessing that your data is largely array-based.  Load elements of that array chunk by chunk.  Start with 10k records at a time and see where that gets you.

You can still use AJAX to fetch the data, since you will have solved the problem of parsing the responses.  However, you might also consider utilizing web sockets to reduce some of the request overhead.  (Or, use HTTP/2 where possible.)

I should also point out that there are streaming parsers available for JSON and XML.  This requires you to be able to get that data stream (web sockets makes this easy), and depends on your data format whether or not it will be useful to you.

If after chunking your data you still have crashes, then it's time to get cozy with the developer tools and profile your memory usage.  There are limits to what you can load in a web page, which vary from browser to browser (and system to system, especially on mobile devices).

**2020 Update:** [Line-delimited (ND-JSON)](http://ndjson.org/) is the usual way to do this chunking.  You can stream the result client-side and parse as you go.  No streaming parser necessary, you just need a transform stream to handle the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but you can split the data in chunks and make multiple calls one after the current has finished ( maybe passing an index for chunk order ). This way you can prevent future surprises if you must get all of 200 MB data

Normally i would get the most important data first than the other part only when needed ( usually a user action )

Comment: That's virtually guaranteed to not solve the OPs problem. If the OP **needs** that 200MB of data, then the memory demands in his application are going to significantly higher than 200MB - even if it is sent a little bit at a time. And that's when the application will fail.

Comment: I know it is a lot of data and don't know why you would need that much once. I would'nt go more than 1mb in one request

Comment: The browser has no problems downloading 200 MB of data. People routinely download files that are several gigabytes large. The problem is *displaying* the data, not *downloading* it. It makes no difference if you make one request to download 200 MB or 200 requests to download 1 MB, other than that the latter is likely to consume more memory and resources.

Comment: @Juhana The problem isn't in the download, it's in the parsing.  See my answer for a fuller explanation.  When you download 200MB, you're not parsing it at the same time.

Comment: @HerbiShtini You can definitely go over 1MB per request.  At the end of the day though, that chunking needs to be tuned to the specific application.

Comment: @Brad I suspect (but haven't measured) that at the end the bottleneck will be the DOM; you just can't have 200 MB worth of non-trivial HTML without the browser choking on it.

Comment: @Brad of course you can but i would not prefer to go more than 1mb, because it may become an issue in performance and also harder to manage

Comment: @Juhana Who said anything about 200MB of HTML?  Just because the data is needed client-side doesn't mean it's directly getting dumped into the DOM.  In fact, it's a safe assumption that it isn't.

Comment: @Brad That would mean that the data contains redundant or unused information. Raw data + HTML markup > raw data alone.

Comment: @Juhana - downloading a 200MB file is far different than reading 200MB of *stuff* into memory and doing stuff with it.

Comment: @Juhana Web pages don't have to just be presentation layers.  Who knows what they actually need to do with this 200MB of data, but undoubtedly there's a whole client-side application doing something with it.